# Join rot13-encoded characters back together

Tags: javascript, string, indexof, caesar-cipher, rot13

This is the challenge:
 **Caesars Cipher-**
the letters are shifted by 13 places. Thus 'A' ↔ 'N', 'Q' ↔ 'D', and so on.

A function that takes a ROT13 encoded string as input and returns a decoded string.
All letters will be uppercase. Don't transform any non-alphabetic character (i.e. spaces, punctuation), but do pass them on.

***I am getting the correct output but currently, each alphabet is a single string. Is there a way to combine all the individual alphabets into one single sentence ***

```
function rot13(str) {
  var original = str.split('')
  var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split('')
  let i = 0;
  while(i<original.length){
  let indexVal = alphabet.indexOf(original[i])
  if(indexVal>= 13){
    indexVal -=13
  }else if(indexVal===-1){
    indexVal = 33
  }
  else{
    indexVal += 13
  }
 var final = alphabet[indexVal]
    i++;
    console.log(final)
  }
}
rot13("SERR CVMMN");//should log FREE PIZZA
/* 
currently logs:
F
R
E
E
undefined
P
I
Z
Z
A
undefined
*/
```

Comment: there are so many ways to implement rot13, like  `function rot13(str) { return str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, char => "NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM"[char.charCodeAt(0) - 65]) }` This one should be simple enough that you can understand it yet something for you to grow and a completely differrent approach to the problem; that's why I don't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

***Figured it out***

```
function rot13(str) {
  var original = str.split('')
  var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split('')
  let i = 0;
  let arr = "";
  while(i<original.length){
  let indexVal = alphabet.indexOf(original[i])
  if(indexVal>= 13){
    indexVal -=13
  }else if(indexVal===-1){
    indexVal = 33
  }
  else{
    indexVal += 13
  }
  arr+=alphabet[indexVal];
  arr = arr.replace(undefined, original[i])

  i++;
  }
  return arr
}
rot13("GUR DHVPX OEBJA SBK WHZCF BIRE GUR YNML QBT.");
```